# How do I determine the zero elements of a Hamiltonian in a 4 ket space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, parity

The Hamiltonian matrix of particle subject to a central potential is described by

$$
H=\begin{pmatrix}
H_{11} & H_{12} & H_{13} & H_{14}\\
H_{21} & H_{22} & H_{23} & H_{24}\\
H_{31} & H_{32} & H_{33} & H_{34}\\
H_{41} & H_{42} & H_{43} & H_{44}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $$ H_{ij}= \langle\phi_i| H |\phi_j \rangle $$

and each component has a wave function on the coordinate space given by

$$
\begin{align}
\langle\textbf{x}|\phi_1\rangle & = e^{-\alpha r} \\
\langle\textbf{x}|\phi_2\rangle & = xe^{-\beta r} \\
\langle\textbf{x}|\phi_3\rangle & = ye^{-\beta r} \\
\langle\textbf{x}|\phi_3\rangle & = ze^{-\beta r} \\
\end{align}
$$

How can I identify which elements are zero?

One hint I received was trying to use the parity ($ \pi $) and the plane reflection ($ \mathcal{O}_{xy}, \mathcal{O}_{xz}, \mathcal{O}_{yz} $) operators, but that didn't really help.